# Конструкторы с геттерами и сеттерами и их работа

Tags: java

Друзья! Я понял как работают сеттеры, геттеры и конструкторы.
Но не понял одну вещь:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class User {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person("Василий");
        System.out.println(person.getName()); 
        person.setName("Леонид");
        System.out.println(person.getName());
    }
}
```

Зачем нам сеттеры, если можно указать всё в конструкторе (в параметрах)?
Может, есть какие-то подводные камни или разные ситуации?

Comment: А что будете делать, если значение свойств становится известно намного позже, чем создание объекта? Что если разные свойства объекта устанавливаются в разных участках кода? Что если состояние объекта должно многократно измениться за время жизни объекта?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev прав. Имя же дается во время "создания" человека так скажем. Но он после совершеннолетия, насколько мне известно, может пойти в паспортный стол и изменить его. Это конкретно к вашему примеру кода

Comment: Больше спасибо всем, всё понял!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через конструктор указывается начальное значение. Такой способ инициализации гарантирует установку значений при создании объекта и сокращает код инициализации этого объекта (не нужно дополнительно вызывать сеттеры). Сеттером же начальные значения можно изменить в процессе жизни объекта, иначе пришлось бы создавать новый объект через конструктор, что часто неприемлемо. Ну и геттером, понятно, получить текущее значение

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы передаёте значения определённых полей во всех конструкторах, вы гарантируете, что эти конкретные поля будут проинициализированы. Сетеры такой гарантии не дают. С другой стороны это не вскегда необходимо, поэтому и не всегда используется.